# Auto width CSS not working for my middle division

Tags: html, css

I have three divisions and try to assign the width for my first and last divisions using CSS calc property. I am trying to assign the middle division width based on calc results. But it is not assigning any width for middle division.

**HTML:**

```
 <div style="width:400px;">
<div class="first">First Division Content Goes Here.</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="last">Second Division Content Goes Here.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .first
{
height:50px;
background-color:#ff00ff;
float:left;
width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.divider
{
width:auto;
height:50px;
background-color:#fff000;    
float:left;
}
.last
{
height:50px;
background-color:#00ffff;
float:left;
width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

What is the problem? How can i assign the width for my middle part based on the result of calc property?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A94xT/)

EDIT:

I have received many answers like "Width auto won't assign a width automatically if there isn't any content inside the div". So that I have updated my jsfiddle with adding a text in my middle part. So now it has some content and need to adjust the width automatically.

[**Updated JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A94xT/3/)

Comment: `divs` won't get auto width applied until it's have any content inside it!

Comment: You can assign the divider `width: 20px`, based on you removing 10px from each side.

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak I have added a text for the middle div. Still same issue. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `calc`, you can use a (very complicated) `calc` expression for its width:

```
.divider
{
    width: calc(100% - 2 * (50% - 50px)); 
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff000;    
    float:left;
}
```

`width: auto` has no effect because your `div` is empty; this is also why the width isn't "snapping" due to the `div` being floated.

Edit: Yeah...the plain 20px is probably the way to go. :)

Edit 2: [Here is an updated Fiddle with the expression above in the stylesheet.](http://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/A94xT/4/)

Comment: I added some content in div. Check my updated question.

Comment: calc expression is working. The issue is, width not assigning to my middle part.

Answer (score 1):

Width auto won't assign a width automatically if there isn't any content inside the div as it adjusts it's width to the content length.

So assign a width manually:

```
.first
{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.divider
{
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff000;    
    float:left;
}
.last
{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00ffff;
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

**EDIT:** Maybe this is what you are looking for, a 3 column grid design. Using calc isn't really the best practice for this, try assigning a percentage of width to each div, it ends being the same with less complexity.

```
.first
{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    float:left;
     width: 40%;
}
.divider
{
    display: inline-block; width: 20%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff000;    
    float:left;
}
.last
{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00ffff;
    float:left;
     width: 40%;
}
```

Check the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/A94xT/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the divider `width: 20px`, based on you removing 10px from each side.

```
.divider {
    width: 20px;
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A94xT/2/)**